# How to generate an attention mask after padding?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

After padding a tensor A which has 4 dimensions [4, **5**, **129**, 24] in second and third dimension to [4, **6**, **136**, 24], how can I generate its' attention mask?

I have figured out two solutions:

- The first one is to create a zero-tensor A_attention that likes A_pad，and then traverse A to fill 1 to relevant position in A_attention.
- The second one is to create attention mask in the padding procedure. But it seems a little troublesome because the initial tensor A has 4 dimensions.

Are there any ways to generate attention mask more efficiently after padding? Is there an API?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the Transformers library from Hugging Face, which provides a really useful [tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest/quicktour.html#build-a-tokenizer-from-scratch).

I suggest you go through the entire quickstart, but in principle, [this is the part](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest/quicktour.html#encoding-multiple-sentences-in-a-batch) you are interested in.

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to say that I want to generate the attention mask in collate_fn(). And I want to pad the label batch_data.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, I implemented this by creating attention mask in the padding procedure.

Comment: Did you use the Transformers library? By the way, I also use the padding=True attribute in the collate function and everything works smoothly.